# How can I execute a block of code exactly once in PHP?

Tags: php

I have one main.php file with a class definition. Other php files use this main.php file

```
//main.php

<?php

class A{


}

//I want to execute the following statements exactly once    

$a = new A();
/*
Some code 
*/


?>
```

I use main.php in other php files like

```
//php1.php
<?php
require_once("main.php");

$b = new A();

/* 
Some code
*/

?>

//php2.php
<?php
require_once("main.php");

$b = new A();

/* 
Some code
*/

?>
```

Is there any statement in PHP like execute_once()?
How do I solve this?

Comment: using require once is what you need. Your file will be included once. Make sure your read the manual for require_once(), include() and include_once();

Comment: If andreas's comment doesn't answer your question, can you explain in more detail what you want to achieve?

Comment: The main.php file will be included by several other php files. I want the code in the main.php file (after the class defn) to be executed exactly once no matter how many files include it. Globally once not locally once.

Comment: I think what Pekka means is why you want to prevent it from executed more than once? Perhaps there is another way of solving your problem?

Comment: You can't include it more than once anyway because you will get a fatal error trying to re-declare the class. so require_once is what you need as andreas says.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One way to make sure that certain code is not executed more than once by third-party scripts that include it, is to create a flag:

```
if (!defined('FOO_EXECUTED')) {
    foo();
    define('FOO_EXECUTED', true);
}
```

The Singleton pattern mentioned elsewhere just forces that all variables that instantiate one class actually point to the same only instance.

Comment: i would really have to agree with you...less overhead here IMO

Comment: @Keshav I don't know what your concern is but PHP scripts run independently one each other.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Thanks. Until recently I did not know php scripts run independent of each other with no data shared with each other!

Answer (score 3):

I think you need the **[Singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)**. It creates just once instance of the class and returns you the same every time you request it.

> In software engineering, the singleton
>   pattern is a design pattern used to
>   implement the mathematical concept of
>   a singleton, by restricting the
>   instantiation  of a class to one
>   object. This is useful when exactly
>   one object is needed to coordinate
>   actions across the system. The concept
>   is sometimes generalized to systems
>   that operate more efficiently when
>   only one object exists, or that
>   restrict the instantiation to a
>   certain number of objects (say, five).
>   Some consider it an anti-pattern,
>   judging that it is overused,
>   introduces unnecessary limitations in
>   situations where a sole instance of a
>   class is not actually required, and
>   introduces global state into an
>   application.

**Update Based On OP Comment:**

Please see this:

**[The Singleton Design Pattern for PHP](http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/singleton.html)**

Comment: How do I implement it in PHP? I got the theory but how do I implement it?

Comment: @Jack googling for the PHP singleton doesn't help?

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: It definitely should help :)

Comment: You might want to add that the Singleton pattern is considered an AntiPattern by a growing number of people. Friends don't let friends use Singletons.

Comment: @Gordon: yup, i have added the whole paragraph now, and yes it was important to show that too :)

Answer (score 1):

Just wrote a class for this.

Since it is called staticly the variable should stick around through the entire application if included in the bootstrap level of your app.

You can also choose to execute code a specific number of times.

```
class exec{    
  public static $ids = array();
  public static function once($id){
    if(isset(static::$ids[$id])){
      return false;
    } else {
      if(isset(static::$ids[$id])){
        static::$ids[$id]++;
      } else {
        static::$ids[$id] = 1;
      }
      return true;
    }
  }
  public static function times($id, $count=1){
    if(isset(static::$ids[$id])){
      if($count == static::$ids[$id]){
        return false;
      } else {
        static::$ids[$id]++;
        return true;
      }
    } else {
      static::$ids[$id] = 1;
      return true;
    }
  }
}

//usage

foreach(array('x', 'y', 'z') as $value){
  if(exec::once('tag')){
    echo $value;
  }
}

//outputs x

foreach(array('x', 'y', 'z') as $value){
  if(exec::times('tag2', 2)){
    echo $value;
  }
}

//outputs xy
```