# How to make a PHP code run only once

Tags: php, html, wordpress

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I execute a block of code exactly once in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2743414/how-can-i-execute-a-block-of-code-exactly-once-in-php)

I have a code that basically checks the current category assigned to the post, and retrieve a code according to it. 
If there are more then 1 categories assigned to the post, it's rendering both the codes or the same one twice..
I wondered if there's an option to make the code to work only once.

```
<?php 
foreach((get_the_category()) as $category){ 
  if($category->cat_ID == '4'){ 
    echo "....TEXT...."; 
  } else { 
    echo "....TEXT2....";
  }
}
?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2743414/how-can-i-execute-a-block-of-code-exactly-once-in-php), [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6709449/run-php-function-once), [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841857/run-the-script-only-once). Use search functionality before posting.

Comment: NONE of those duplicate answers answer this question even remotely.

Comment: @eykanal: The only similarities between this question and those supposed duplicates are the titles.

Comment: perheps run the foreach first, save the result in case it is twice in a variable, then display the the variable whatever if is twice or once, just display one time of course after the foreach

Comment: @ADW - you're right, mea culpa. There *was* an identical question to this just a few days ago and it just set me off, and a quick search showed the other "dupes", but these aren't the one I was thinking of.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$first = true;    
foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) { 
        if($category->cat_ID == '4') { 
           echo "....TEXT....";
           $first = false;
        } else { 
           echo "....TEXT2....";}
           $first = false;
        }

        if(!$first) break;
    }
```

Comment: This code will execute unnecessarily multiple times and therefore spend more resources...

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean, let me think of a better solution.

Comment: No need, just take a look at my answer ;)

Comment: haha, just outa curiosity, how about now?

Comment: If statement and $first variable are unnecessary...

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<?php 
foreach((get_the_category()) as $category){ 
  if($category->cat_ID == '4'){ 
    echo "....TEXT...."; 
  } else { 
    echo "....TEXT2....";
  }
  break;
}

?>
```

Break is used to get out of loop regardless of the condition. Please refer to [this](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php) article for manual.

Comment: This will not work because it will break out even if the category isn't 4 :D

Comment: No, because the loop will execute only once...

Answer (score 1):

Add a variable to the inside of the loop that flags the code as run. Then check for that variable before running:

```
<?php 
   if($first_run) {
      foreach((get_the_category()) as $category){ 
         if($category->cat_ID == '4'){ 
               echo "....TEXT...."; 
         } 
         else { 
               echo "....TEXT2....";
         }
        }
      $first_run = TRUE;
      }
        ?>
```

This will only work if you have the code called from a function or if you are including it multiple times in the same script. If you want it to only run once per session (across several pages), you should use a [`SESSION`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) variable.

Answer (score 0):

complementing my comment above.

```
<?php 
      foreach((get_the_category()) as $category){ 
         if($category->cat_ID == '4'){ 
               $varCateg = "....TEXT...."; 
         } 
         else { 
               $varCateg = "....TEXT...."; 
         }
        }

// diplay varCateg here
echo $varCateg; 

?>
```

doing this will not show up the categ twice.